# file explorer in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, explorer

Hi:
In my application,I have a specified folder in the server side,the client user(authencitationed) can upload/delete file and create/delete folder under this directory.
The common user can broser the uploaded files.

It sounds like a editable file explorer,I wonder if there is any exist solution?

UPDATE:

When I say the common user can browser the files,I do not mean that they can just see the file names,but the content of the file,in fact,the type of the file to be uploaded are just txt/html format,so they can be inserted in to the page easily.

I have thougth use the treeview to list all the folder and files in the left of the page,when user click a file node,the content of this file should displayed in the right of the page,also there should be some controls to delete/add/ the file or folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jQuery for this....

try using JQuery Tree plugin to create the explorer....
read this [Tutorial](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/) could be of help
---this would create the explorer which you want.
Now right-clicking on upload you open up a dialog to allow user enter the document and push upload button

and have the JQGrid to display your documents...

use jquery [Forms](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin to upload your files by using c sharp code to upload the files

by json stringify your javascript data and upload it using file properties of c sharp....

i have done it so u can try

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://ckfinder.com/demo

I have used [DevExpress FileManager](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/FileManager/CustomThumbnails.aspx) component but that's a paid one.

Comment: The ckfinder is built based on php.